# How to simplify $\hat{x}$?

Tags: vectors

$\vec{b} = (-n+2\hspace{1cm}-n+3 ...-1\hspace{1cm}0\hspace{1cm}1)^T$

The solution of $A_{n}\vec{x}=\vec{b}$ is $\vec{x}=(1\hspace{1cm}1\hspace{1cm}1)^{T}$

Perturb $\vec{b}$ to $\hat{b}=\vec{b}+(0...0\hspace{1cm}\epsilon)^{T}$

Let $\hat{x}$ be the solution to $A_{n}\vec{x}=\vec{b}$. What is $\hat{x}$?

I know that $\hat{x}$ = $\vec{x}+(A_{n})^{-1}(\hat{b}-\vec{b})$.

In other words, $\hat{x}$ = $(1\hspace{1cm}1\hspace{1cm}1)^{T}+(A_{n})^{-1}((-n+2\hspace{1cm}-n+3 ...-1\hspace{1cm}0\hspace{1cm}1)^T+(0...0\hspace{1cm}\epsilon)^{T}-(-n+2\hspace{1cm}-n+3 ...-1\hspace{1cm}0\hspace{1cm}1)^T)$

,but I can't simplify this further.

Edit:
The matrix is

$A_{n}$ = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 & -1& \ldots & -1\\
0 & 1 & -1 & \ldots & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \ddots &\vdots\\
\vdots & \vdots &  \ddots & \ddots & -1\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Note that $\hat b-\vec b=[0,0,\cdots,0,\epsilon]^T=\epsilon[0,0,\cdots,0,1]^T$. So try to evaluate $A_n^{-1}[0,0,\cdots,0,1]^T$.

Comment: In other words, solve $A_n\vec y=[0,\cdots,0,1]^T$ for $\vec y$. You don't need to explicitly calculate the inverse $A_n^{-1}$.